PlotlyとDashを使って任意の数の図を作成する方法は？
PlotlyとDashをを使って、任意の数の図を作成する方法を探しています。
自分の理解では "figures =" の部分に図を追加すれば大丈夫だと思いますが、その方法がわかりません。
別の方法としては、 df.select(category).unique() ですべての因子の数だけ図を作成して、選択した図だけ表示させる方法でも構いません。
わかる方がおられましたら、ご教授をお願いします。
現在のコード
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.subplots as sp
    
from plotly.offline import plot
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
    
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
    
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id="my_dropdown_Component1",
        options=[{"value": category_local, "label": category_local} for category_local in pl.Series(df.select(category).unique()).to_list()],
        value=["H1"],
        multi=True
    ),
    dcc.Graph(id="my_graph")
])

@app.callback(Output("my_graph", "figure"), Input("my_dropdown_Component1", "value"))
def update_graph(selected_C1):
    ###現在2つの図を描いておりますが、Dropdownで選んだ数だけ図を表示したいです。
    figures = [
        px.scatter([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5]),
        px.scatter([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5])
    ]
    
    fig = make_subplots(rows=len(figures), cols=1)
    
    for i, figure in enumerate(figures):
        for trace in range(len(figure["data"])):
            fig.append_trace(figure["data"][trace], row=i+1, col=1)
    
    return fig

app.run_server()


こんな記事が参考になるかもしれませんね。Pythonを使って簡単にできるビジネスインテリジェンスツール開発, Python Dashによりデータ分析結果の共有を効率化する取り組み, Dashのつまづきやすいポイント解説, Plotly Dashを使ってインタラクティブなダッシュボードを作成する

「現在2つの図を描いておりますが、Dropdownで選んだ数だけ図を表示したい」・・・とコメントに記されていますが, そうすればいいだけに思えます (selected_C1 は選んだ項目のリストなので)。何を疑問に思っているのかがわかりません。

@kunif ありがとうございます。使い始めたばかりの為勉強させていただきます。

@oriri selected_C1を3要因選ばれたら、それについての図3つを表示させる、4つの場合は4つの図という具合に操作をしたかったんです。説明が良くなくすみません。


自分の理解では figures = の部分に図を追加すれば大丈夫だと思いますが、その方法がわかりません。
別の方法としては、 df.select(category).unique() ですべての因子の数だけ図を作成して、選択した図だけ表示させる方法でも構いません。

グラフ用のデータがすでに存在する(用意してある)ものとして
あとは dcc.Dropdown() にて選択した項目に該当するデータを描画対象にするだけ, のように思えます
df.select(category) が ['H1', 'H2', 'H3', ...] だとすれば, 以下のようにできます
(グラフを区別できるよう, 少しずつデータの数値を変更している)
def update_graph(selected_C1):
    if selected_C1 is None or selected_C1 == []:
        return None

    vals = np.arange(5) +1

    figures = []
    if 'H1' in selected_C1: figures.append(px.scatter(x=[1,2,3,4,5], y=vals *1))
    if 'H2' in selected_C1: figures.append(px.scatter(x=[1,2,3,4,5], y=vals *1.5))
    if 'H3' in selected_C1: figures.append(px.scatter(x=[1,2,3,4,5], y=vals *2))
    if 'H4' in selected_C1: figures.append(px.scatter(x=[1,2,3,4,5], y=vals *3))



もし質問している内容が, この回答と方向性が違うなどの場合は,
質問をもう少し詳しく記すか, あるいはコメントにて対応してください

(update !)
少し短く記述
先に辞書などを用意しておいて, update_graph() で短いコードで参照
データの持ち方, categoryからどのようにしてデータを得るのか不明なため
適当に生成しています
グラフの順番は, 選択の順番で描画されることになる
vals = np.arange(5) +1
figs = {
    'H1': dict(x=[1,2,3,4,5], y=vals *1),
    'H2': dict(x=[1,2,3,4,5], y=vals *1.5),
    'H3': dict(x=[1,2,3,4,5], y=vals *2),
    'H4': dict(x=[1,2,3,4,5], y=vals *3),
}

def update_graph(selected_C1):
    if selected_C1 is None or selected_C1 == []:
        return None

    figures = [px.scatter(**figs[cat])for cat in selected_C1 if cat in figs]

    fig = make_subplots(rows=len(figures), cols=1)


ありがとうございます。まさしく、これが行いたかったです。figures.append()で入れて、その後にデータを取りだす部分で少し苦労しかしたが、oriri様が示してくれた部分で十分説明をいただけれましたので、感謝しています。

データの持ち方など, あえて単純にしていますが, (データなど) 工夫すればもう少し短くスッキリ記述できるかもしれません
